# Representation of xmlcast result with delimeters in Pl/SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am a bit new to PL/SQL, I have a following problem:

I have xml with following structure(b.response):

```
<a>
  <b>
    ...
    <ruleList>
      <number>2</number>
      <rule>
        <name>test1</name>
      </rule>
      <rule>
        <name>test2</name>
      </rule>
    </ruleList>
  </b>
</a>
```

I use the following script to parse needed values from XML:

```
SELECT 
xmlcast(xmlquery('/a/b/ruleList/number' passing b.response returning content)as varchar2(1000)) rules_number,
xmlcast(xmlquery('/a/b/ruleList/rule[*]/name'passing b.response returning content)as varchar2(1000)) values
FROM test b
```

And have following result:

```
rules_number | values
           2 | test1test2
```

My question is how can I enter delimeters between names using xmlcast? So the result should be following:

```
rules_number | values
           2 | test1, test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
xmlcast(xmlquery('string-join(/a/b/ruleList/number/text(),",")' passing b.response returning content)as varchar2(1000)) rules_number,
xmlcast(xmlquery('string-join(/a/b/ruleList/rule[*]/name/text(),",")' passing b.response returning content)as varchar2(1000)) values
FROM test b
```

- `/text()` is extracting value of node not full node
- `string-join` - join string sequence using delimiter

Better choice in your case is xmltable.

```
select * from   xmltable( '/a/b/ruleList' passing xmltype( '<a>
  <b>

    <ruleList>
      <number>2</number>
      <rule>
        <name>test1</name>
      </rule>
      <rule>
        <name>test2</name>
      </rule>
    </ruleList>
  </b>
</a>') 
columns 
rules_number varchar2(1000) path 'string-join(number/text(),",")',
"values" varchar2(1000) path 'string-join(rule/name/text(),",")'
);
```